# Wordpress + angularJS route + SEO

Tags: wordpress, angularjs, seo

I'm currently on a project where I want to have :

- **Wordpress** for easy content managment.
- **AngularJS** for some UX (the goal is to have no page reload + nice animation between pages loading) + further functionalities.
- And care about the **SEO**.

In that purpose, I'm using Angular's Route module to get the user a smoother experience, and using the Angular HTML5 "pretty urls" mode to "hook" the page switching (No hashbang -> natural links).

I don't want to generate hashbangs because it's more difficult to maintain (HTML snapshots with phantom.js server etc...) than just leaving Wordpress generate the content as he does it well.

So my intention was to let angularJS controls the user's navigation, and wordpress to generate the content when user will F5 & for the SEO bots(No JS).

But I can't find a clean & clear solution to this problem because either the Angular way will work, either the "PHP" way will work.

Any ideas will be welcome ! :)

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress already provides you with **wp_ajax_** hook for AJAX requests. ( [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)))

Example:

```
mysite.com/my-test-page
```

### Wordpress

In this simple case we need our *wp_ajax_* hook to retrieve a page by it's *slug*.

One easy way is to use `get_page_by_path($page_path, $output, $post_type)`, to get the page we want where *$page_path* is the slug.

Then return the page data as JSON, `return json_encode($pageArray);`

---

### AngularJS

Route: Do a simple GET:

```
.when('/:page_slug', {
    templateUrl: 'views/page.html',
    controller: 'PageController',
    resolve: {
      page : function($route) {
        return $http.get(wp_ajax_url, 
                          {
                          'action': 'the_ajax_hook', 
                          'data': $route.current.params.page_slug
                          }
                        );
     }
    }
  })
```

---

### SEO

Google recently announced they are updating the Webmaster Tools to show you how a Javascript generated site renders and provide you with tips on how to make your site crawl-able.

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html

Apart from that you can use other services to make your site SEO-friendly today:

- [getseojs.com](http://getseojs.com/)
- [brombone.com](http://www.brombone.com)
- [prerender.io](https://prerender.io/)

Comment: Good answer. Though I'm having difficulty with this approach when applying this logic to more complex queries, i.e. when the slug does not represent a page, but a post, category etc.. 
E.g. in the above example, how would you set the correct `$post_type` for `get_page_by_path()` given only a `page_slug` that happens to represent a `post`.
I suppose it would require more information from `parse_request()` in WordPress.

Comment: @PimSchaaf Best option would be to use ID's instead of slug and for more complex queries like from a category, pagination etc you can add more parameters in the http data. 

ex. ````{
'action': 'the_ajax_hook', 
'data': {type: 'category', id: 23}
}````

.. or for post.
````{
'action': 'the_ajax_hook', 
'data': {type: 'post', id: 897}
}````

In your php you can return accordingly.

Comment: Have you tried a REST approach? ie. https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/
 
 That would make it much easier to use with Angular + Restangular.